# Rdgal don't working well to save a shapefile

Tags: r, r-sp, rgdal

I'm trying to save a shapefile format with detection rates using the "rgdal" packages, but the following error occurs:

```
Error in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") : 
  Can't parse PROJ.4-style parameter string
+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84+datum=WGS84+no_def
```

How to fix?

Reproductive example

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(camtrapR)

Long<-c(-53.59390711, -53.58148303)
Lat<-c(-4.633924739, -4.6340598)
df1<-data.frame(Long,Lat)
df1$Station<-NA
df1[df1$Long=="-53.59390711",]$Station<-"w"
df1[df1$Long=="-53.58148303",]$Station<-"z"

Station<-c("w","w","w","w","w","w","w","w","w","w","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z")
Species<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c")
df2<-data.frame(Station, Species)


detectionMaps(CTtable=df1,recordTable=df2,Xcol="Long",Ycol="Lat",stationCol="Station",speciesCol="Species",speciesToShow="a",richnessPlot=FALSE,speciesPlots=FALSE,
writeShapefile=TRUE,shapefileDirectory=tempdir(),shapefileName="sp_a", shapefileProjection="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_def")

#The shapefile should be created in this directory: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Comment: This code works for me. Are you looking in the right directory? You can check using `tempdir()`. Also make sure your proj4 string has spaces between arguments.

Comment: @at80, thanks you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue connected to the change from PROJ4 to PROJ6 in rgdal/sp. For you the issue is a bit deeper because the `camtrapR` package is not yet updated to deal with PROJ6.You can read more about the transition to PROJ6 [here](http://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/PROJ6_GDAL3.html).

Without going too deep into it the solution for you would be to downgrade to an older version of `sp` and `rgdal`.

For sp (< 1.4-2) and rgdal (< 1.5-8).

EDIT: Since you can define the PROJ String yourself you can also first try: "+init=epsg:4326". This might still work.